# EventListener for Object removed from memcached

Tags: java, oop, memcached, spymemcached

i am using memcached server to store some object with different expire times, is there some way to add event listener on removal or expiration of that object?
Currently i'm using spymemcached client.
How can i achieve that i do some cleanup just before my object is deleted/expires.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to register an event listener on memcached server. Also, expired objects are lazily removed from memcached. This means that an expired item will only be removed if you try to get an item that has already expired or if the server runs out of memory and needs to make more room. If you are deleting an item then the item is removed immediately.